# Dataframe: index values difference calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a Python dataframe (based on some criteria) I am able to select the index value (a date)  (='first date') as well as the index value (a date) corresponding to the very last row ('last date').

I would like to calculate explicitly the difference (in days) between 'first date' and 'last date'  (should be = 3 (number of days)). How can I do it for this case?

Many thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['2021-3-22', '2021-3-23', '2021-3-24', '2021-3-25', '2021-3-26'],
"x": ['1', 1, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan' ]})
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1

    
date         x  
2021-3-22   1
2021-3-23   1
2021-3-24   nan
2021-3-25   nan
2021-3-26   nan

print('first date:', df1.x[df1.x == 1].tail(1).index.values)
first date: ['2021-3-23']
(=d1)

print('last date:', df1.tail(1).index.values)
last date: ['2021-3-26']
(=d2)

d2-d1=?
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the type of the `'date'` column. Currently, it is a `string` but you want it to be a `datetime` instance instead.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['2021-3-22', '2021-3-23', '2021-3-24', '2021-3-25', '2021-3-26'],
"x": ['nan', 1, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan' ]})

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

df1 = df1.set_index('date')
```

Now you can do:

```
df1.index[-1] - df1.index[0] #Timedelta('4 days 00:00:00')
```

or

```
(df1.index[-1] - df1.index[0]).days #4
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! In this case, for df1 I would like to extract the index value  which corresponds to the last 1 observed. When I do df1.x[df1.x == 1].tail(1).index.values, I have the following output: array(['2021-03-23T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')... In case, do you know if there is an alternative to this (so that to get the index format in the same value as df1.index[-1])? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Champion try using Datraframe.loc `df1.loc[df1.x == 1].index[-1]` for more info check the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the date's or index values in datetime format. You can either use datetime library or use pandas to do it. As your requirement you can do the following

```
(pd.to_datetime(df1.tail(1).index.values, format='%Y-%m-%d') 
 - pd.to_datetime(df1.x[df1.x == 1].tail(1).index.values, format='%Y-%m-%d')).days[0]
```

The pd.to_datetime will convert the string values in the required date format